# Is it possible to retrieve arbitrary number of items from reddit using API?

Tags: api, reddit

I am writing a small assistant app to read (well, filter/rank) /r/programming/ for me, because it has so many damn posts, and because certain area of my coding skills was getting rusty and it sounds like good exercise.

I am getting items from "new" page of the subreddit using json api; however it only returns 25 items per request (which is the page size), so to retrieve items for, say, last week, I need to make dozens of requests. As the mandated request interval is 2s, it is painful.

I wonder if there's some way to retrieve more items? Query string parameters for standard html gets also work for json gets, but I cannot find one for page size.

EDIT: for posterity, the paramrter name is "limit", although that too is capped at 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for posterity, the parameter name is "limit", although that too is capped at 100